# UnsatisfiedLinkError using JSNI with vaadin

Tags: vaadin, jsni, vaadin-spring-boot

I have created a Vaadin project, and I used JSNI for scripting. But when execution reaches at JSNI script, it shows an error.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.yty.cws.CiwsUI.jsniDemo()V
    at com.yty.cws.CiwsUI.jsniDemo(Native Method) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.yty.cws.CiwsUI.lambda$0(CwsUI.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
```

The following is my sample code.

```
public class CiwsUI extends UI{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5275145103992848572L;
    VerticalLayout mainLayout=new VerticalLayout();
    private TextField txtName=new TextField();
    private Button btnJSNI=new Button("JSNI");
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {

        mainLayout.addComponents(txtName,btnJSNI);
        setContent(mainLayout);
        mainLayout.setComponentAlignment(txtName, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
        mainLayout.setComponentAlignment(btnJSNI, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
        btnJSNI.addClickListener(e->{
            System.out.println("Clicked");
            jsniDemo();
        });
    }
    private native void jsniDemo()/*-{
    $wnd.alert("Hai JSNI");
    }-*/;

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [differences between GWT & Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/comparison) you'll notice that besides the cliend-side API, Vaadin also has a server-side API, and the code you posted falls into that category. Searching the Vaadin forum I found [this question](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/1425254/1488747) with your exact problem. Adding below the reply of Henry Sara from the Vaadin dev team:

> JSNI is only usable in the client side widgets whereas you are working
> on the server side.
>
> Use Window.executeJavaScript("...") (Vaadin 6) or
> Root.executeJavaScript("...") (Vaadin 7) if you need to execute
> JavaScript from your server side application.

While things may have changed since the answer and `Root.executeJavaScript("...");` is now probably `JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(...)");`, the Vaadin docs offer information on [javascript interactions to and from the serverside](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-javascript.html) as well as on [js components and extensions](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/gwt/gwt-javascript.html) and also, you can check the [wiki](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Integrating%20a%20JavaScript%20library%20as%20an%20extension) for more examples.